# Can I route my wireless traffic through a Linux server?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, routing

I have a D-Link DSL-2750U ADSL router at home. All the devices in my house connect to the router through the Wi-Fi signal that it broadcasts.

Is it possible to route all the WLAN traffic received by the router to a Linux server for filtering and then back through the router's WAN connection?

Comment: You misunderstand what a router is. A router routes packets between networks, not from a network back to the same network. What it sounds like you want to do is set up the server as a WAP and have your devices associate with that, instead.

Comment: What I want to do is make use of the home router that I already have and add proxy onto this router to filter packets and control access to content. If there is way to change the routing tables on the router to route all the wifi traffic through the proxy and then out, thats what I want to do.

Comment: As I wrote, routers do not route from a network back to the same network. Routers route between networks. The way routing table work is that they will be used if the packet needs to travel to a different network, otherwise they are dropped. Your confusion comes from the fact that the same chassis holding your router also has a bridge. The router has two ports: WAN and LAN, and the router only deals with traffic passing between those to networks.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see why not. But if your router support it in its native firmware is something else completely.

E.g. configure all wireless devices to use your router as default gateway. That way all their traffic heads there first. Say use 172.16.42.0/16 as network, and 172.16.42.1 as gateway.

Then on the router configure a static route from everything from 172.16.42.0/16 to one specific host. Say using wired networking here with 10.0.0.0/24. That way all traffic arrives at the linux host you want to filter it with.

Have the Linux host filter. Use a second NIC leading to the router or assing two IPs to the same NIC (say 192.168.3.0/24 as third network) and forward everything after filtering to this network. For the linux host this might simply be setting the default gateway to 192.168.3.1/24 and assigning 192.168.3.1 to the endpoint on the wireless-acesspoint/router/multi-thingy.

Traffic in the wireless-acesspoint/router/multi-thingy does its normal thing (no special filtering on 192.168.3.0/24, just on 172.16.42.0/16) and forwards it normally to the Internet.

So yeah, I think it is possible.

It the long way around though and traffic passes needlessly though the same device twice.  Using a single AP connected to the Linux filter host and a separate router/modem would be much cleaner. And likely faster. And easier to maintain. And probably would not require a few hours of research on how to archieve the setup which I descriped (which probably means starting with flashing tomatoe or OpenWRT onto the router since I doubt any SOHO router has this as an option in its web interface.).

Recap: Yeah, it can be done. And no, do not do it. But a EUR15 AP if needed and split the tasks over two devices.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I will try it out and see if I can get it implemented. I'll let you know how it goes.